# Better Algorithm to find the maximum number who's square divides K :

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

Given a number **K** which is a product of two different numbers (A,B), find the maximum number(<=A & <=B) who's square divides the **K** .

Eg : K = 54 (6*9) . Both the numbers are available i.e 6 and 9.

My approach is fairly very simple or trivial.

1. taking the smallest of the two ( 6 in this case).Lets say **A**
2. Square the number and divide K, if its a perfect division, that's the number.
3. Else A = A-1 ,till A =1.

For the given example, 3*3 = 9 divides K, and hence 3 is the answer.

Looking for a better algorithm, than the trivial solution.

**Note :** The test cases are in 1000's so the best possible approach is needed.

Comment: is k = 3 or what?  you could use a for statement that goes through and completes the function and checks if result is decimal or not.

Comment: @Bot K = 54 which is a product of A =6 and B =9, the problem seeks positive integer numbers only. I am already running a for loop , more specifically :

Comment: generally, finding factors of numbers is not easy what I would do is try every square number from 4 to sqrt(k), which should be fairly quick

Comment: so you can test 6 ^2 and 9^2 divided by 54. Then find max num that can by divided by 54 to result in integer.

Comment: what will your algorithm do if the given numbers where 1 * 54?

Comment: @MauricioTrajano Since we are to find the "maximum" number who's square divides K, I took it from the lesser of the two factors (given square of any number above the lesser factor (A) cannot divide the K) and then moved towards , shouldn't that lesser the times (loops), we force?

However, the I think the iteration will pretty much result in the same, as the SQRT of 54 is more than 6. (7+)

Comment: @mGouda fairly simple, 1*54 =54, 1^2 divides the number perfectly, so 1 is the answer.

Comment: @SushimMukulDutta, wrong..for the case of 54 it might by accedently the answer. but assume K=100, we know that the answer is 10 (the maximum number whose square divides K). So if the input was 100 = 1 * 100, the above algorithm will output 1 which is not the max possible output. Actually, I am confused about the need for the 2 values A and B

Comment: @mGouda A=B is also a possibility, so the answer can be 10 given A=1 and B =100.

Comment: so, after the edit, the output must be <=A & <=B. in my example 10 is not acceptable as it does not satisfy this condition where A=1, B=100. So, 10 <= B is true. while 10 <= A is false

Comment: Yes, correct, however, given A =10, and B =10, the answer should be 10. This was my first clause that I already added to the program.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure someone else will come up with a nice answer involving modulus arithmetic.  Here is a naive approach...

Each of the factors can themselves be factored (though it might be an expensive operation).

Given the factors, you can then look for groups of repeated factors.

For instance, using your example:

Prime factors of 9: 3, 3

Prime factors of 6: 2, 3

All prime factors: 2, 3, 3, 3

There are two 3s, so you have your answer (the square of 3 divides 54).

Second example of 36 x 9 = 324

Prime factors of 36: 2, 2, 3, 3

Prime factors of 9: 3, 3

All prime factors: 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3

So you have two 2s and four 3s, which means 2x3x3 is repeated.  2x3x3 = 18, so the square of 18 divides 324.

**Edit: python prototype**

```
import math

def factors(num, dict):
    """ This finds the factors of a number recursively.
        It is not the most efficient algorithm, and I 
        have not tested it a lot.  You should probably
        use another one. dict is a dictionary which looks
        like {factor: occurrences, factor: occurrences, ...}
        It must contain at least {2: 0} but need not have 
        any other pre-populated elements.  Factors will be added
        to this dictionary as they are found.
    """

    while (num % 2 == 0):
        num /= 2
        dict[2] += 1
    i = 3
    found = False
    while (not found and (i <= int(math.sqrt(num)))):
        if (num % i == 0):
            found = True
            factors(i, dict)
            factors(num / i, dict)
        else:
            i += 2
    if (not found):
        if (num in dict.keys()):
            dict[num] += 1
        else:
            dict[num] = 1
    return 0


#MAIN ROUTINE IS HERE

n1 = 37 # first number (6 in your example)
n2 = 41 # second number (9 in your example)
dict = {2: 0} # initialise factors (start with "no factors of 2")
factors(n1, dict) # find the factors of f1 and add them to the list
factors(n2, dict) # find the factors of f2 and add them to the list
sqfac = 1
# now find all factors repeated twice and multiply them together
for k in dict.keys():
    dict[k] /= 2
    sqfac *= k ** dict[k]
# here is the result
print(sqfac)
```

Comment: nice idea, but beside the cost. Although it guarantees that the output divides K but how does it guarantee it is the max possible output?

Comment: @Tony great idea, however, the cost of finding prime factors of the factors and then finding the intersection of the two sets, is what I am bit skeptical about. Giving it a try though, will let you know , thanks :)

Comment: @SushimMukulDutta, I have added a roughshod Python implementation.  I can't currently work out a way to avoid finding all the factors and then looking for pairs.  Looking for pairs once you have factored is low-cost.  Factoring can be expensive, but if you have to find the factors, you have to find them!  There are smarter ways to factor than my `factors` function.

Comment: @mGouda, any number N whose square divides K must be a product of some subset S of the prime factors of K.  Furthermore, if N^2 is to divide K, the subset S had better appear exactly twice in the prime factors of K.  Just find all the prime factors which appear exactly twice (repeats are allowed, so 2, 2, 2, 2 is 2 appearing exactly twice and 2 appearing exactly twice), and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

***Answer in C++***

```
int func(int i, j)
{ 
    int k = 54
    float result = pow(i, 2)/k
    if (static_cast<int>(result)) == result) 
    {
        if(i < j)
        {
            func(j, i);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Number is correct: " << i << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Number is wrong" << endl;
        func(j, i)

    }
 }
```

**Explanation:**

First recursion then test if result is a positive integer if it is then check if the other multiple is less or greater if greater recursive function tries the other multiple and if not then it is correct. Then if result is not positive integer then print Number is wrong and do another recursive function to test j.

Comment: I am bit unsure if you have got the question correctly. Here is a another example. 

Let's try a visual approach, given a rectangle of L =6 and B =9, divide the rectangle into perfect squares with no area left. The task is to find the maximum value of the side of the squares that will be cut.

Comment: so (6 -> 9)/54  is maximum value

Answer (score 0):

If I got the problem correctly, I see that you have a rectangle of length=A, width=B, and area=K 
And you want convert it to a square and lose the minimum possible area

If this is the case. So the problem with your algorithm is not the cost of iterating through mutliple iterations till get the output.
Rather the problem is that your algorithm depends heavily on the length A and width B of the input rectangle.
While it should depend only on the area K

**For example:**

- Assume A =1, B=25
- Then K=25 (the rect area)
- Your algorithm will take the minimum value, which is A and accept it as answer with a single
  iteration which is so fast but leads to wrong asnwer as it will result in a square of area 1 and waste the remaining 24 (whatever cm
  or m)
- While the correct answer here should be 5. which will never be reached by your algorithm

So, in my solution I assume a single input K

My ideas is as follows

- x = sqrt(K)
- if(x is int) .. x is the answer
- else loop from x-1 till 1, x--
- if K/x^2 is int, x is the answer

This might take extra iterations but will guarantee accurate answer
Also, there might be some concerns on the cost of sqrt(K)
but it will be called just once to avoid misleading length and width input